# How can I un-collapse all cell outputs in a VS Code Jupyter Notebook at once?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook where the output from every cell has suddenly been collapsed (I must have done something, so automatically collapse all cells at once).

Here is an example of what I mean by a collapsed cell using the below code: [screenshot of collapsed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXzNJ.png)

```py
print('Why am I collapsed?')
```

The output can be un-collapsed by pressing the lower and smaller blue bar: [screenshot of uncollapsed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xujgr.png)

My notebook is quite long, so I would like to un-collapse every cell at once instead of having to press the un-collapse button/bar on every single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Notebook: Expand All Outputs` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). If you want to bind it to a keyboard shortcut, its command ID is `notebook.cell.expandAllCellOutputs`.

Note that there is also a command to expand all cell inputs (`notebook.cell.expandAllCellInputs`).